# Ignite C++, Server-client cluster load balancing performance issue

Tags: ignite, node-cluster

I have 2 nodes, in which im trying to run 4 ignite servers, 2 on each node and 16 ignite clients, 8 on each node. I am using replicated cache mode. I could see the load on cluster is not distributed eventually to all servers.

My intension of having 2 servers per node is to split the load of 8 local clients to local servers and server can work in write behind to replicate the data across all servers.

But I could notice that only one server is  taking the load, which is running at 200% cpu and other 3 servers are running at very less usage of around 20%cpu. How can I setup the cluster to  eventually distribute the client loads across all servers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you generate the load? Which cache operations do you perform?

Comment: I'm generating load by inserting same value 1Million times and trying to get the value using the same key. This is done asynchronously from different clients running on the two nodes.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm generating load by inserting same value 1Million times and trying to get the value using the **same key**

Here is your problem. Same key is always stored on the same Ignite node, according to Affinity Function (see https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-grid), so only one node takes read and write load.

You should use a wide range of keys instead.